# odoo 12 show different forms based on state values

Tags: odoo-12

How to show different forms on odoo 12 based on state value. I want a switch between the states to alter the form as well while keeping the same tree view of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could create a single form create different groups in the form or even further add different notebooks and pages whose visibility can be controlled using attributes and passing in a state change in a domain.

Answer (score 1):

you can't have two different form view based on the state from a single tree view. But you can control fields/groups/pages or other elements visibility based on state using the invisible attribute.

Comment: That is true, actually even a single form with multiple groups and notebooks and pages whose visibility can be controlled based on attributes then passing in a domain to check the state works perfectly well

Comment: yes, you can use the domain, groups (user access), context and many other features to show a single form in different ways for different users or for different states or for different values.